# Prove that a given mapping is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$Problem$

If $\phi$ is an isomorphism from a group $G$ under addition to a group $\overline G$ under addition. Prove that for any integer n,the mapping from$ G$ to $\overline G $ defined by $\gamma(x)$ =n$\phi(x)$is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\overline G$.

$Attempt$

$\gamma(x+y)$ = n( $\phi(x+y)$)= n+$\phi(x)$+ $\phi(y)$ .

Is this right ?

Or

$\gamma(x+y)$ = n( $\phi(x+y)$)= n+$\phi(x)$+ n+$\phi(y)$ .

Is this right ?

Comment: Are your groups abelian?

Comment: Nothing like that mentioned.

Comment: What's the meaning of $n+\phi(x)+\phi(y)$?

Comment: Sorry posted my comment as an answer

Comment: I have flagged it.

Comment: A group under addition is *usually* meant to be abelian. It’s not true if $\overline G$ is not abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not quite on track. In the setting of an additive group, $ny$ is shorthand for $y+\cdots+y$ ($n$ instances of $y$ added together). If the group is *abelian*, then we have the nice property that $nx+ny=n(x+y)$ for any $x,y$ in the group, but otherwise, we may not.

Assuming that your groups are abelian, then, we can say that $$\gamma(x+y)=n\phi(x+y)=n\bigl(\phi(x)+\phi(y)\bigr)=n\phi(x)+n\phi(y)=\gamma(x)+\gamma(y),$$ as desired. Some texts tacitly treat additive groups as abelian, and use other notation for non-abelian groups. It may be that yours mentioned something to this effect early on, that you missed/forgot. Or it could be a misprint.